# Finding the next closes airport from a set of GPS coordinates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of airport coordinates as defined [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat) which I'm attempting to perform calculations on in excel.

I want to find the next closest airport for any given airports' coordinates.

---

The closest I've been able to get is the use of the formula  :

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$20,MATCH(MIN(SQRT(($B$1:$B$20-E1)^2+($C$1:$C$20-F1)^2)),SQRT(($B$1:$B$20-E1)^2+($C$1:$C$20-F1)^2),0),1)`

as shown on [this page](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/537429-closest-neighbour-coordinates.html).

---

However, this formula will provide the closest *named* location (i.e the airport) to a given set of coordinates.

How can I find the *next* closest airport?

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Just wondering why you accepted the most complicated formula?

Comment: @R3uK because i tried the answers in order and the first one worked...

Comment: Ahah! Ok, I understand now! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help, copy the below formula in D2 with shif+ctrl+enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$19,MATCH(MIN(IF($B$2:$B$19&$C$2:$C$19=B2&C2,99999,ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-$B$2:$B$19))*COS(RADIANS(90-B2))+SIN(RADIANS(90-$B$2:$B$19))*SIN(RADIANS(90-B2))*COS(RADIANS($C$2:$C$19-C2)))*6371)),IF($B$2:$B$19&$C$2:$C$19=B2&C2,99999,ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-$B$2:$B$19))*COS(RADIANS(90-B2))+SIN(RADIANS(90-$B$2:$B$19))*SIN(RADIANS(90-B2))*COS(RADIANS($C$2:$C$19-C2)))*6371),0),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. As an add on question, how can I limit the results to those airports that have a flag in a fifth column 'G'?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SMALL` formula :

`SMALL({array};Nth)` and `LARGE({array};Nth)` will return respectively 
the Nth smallest and largest value of a set!

your formula updated :

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$20,MATCH(SMALL(SQRT(($B$1:$B$20-E1)^2+($C$1:$C$20-F1)^2),2),SQRT(($B$1:$B$20-E1)^2+($C$1:$C$20-F1)^2),0),1)
```