# Next closest airport in excel which also match specific criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111618/finding-the-next-closes-airport-from-a-set-of-gps-coordinates-in-excel) which covers finding the next closes airport in a list which has the airport code, longitude and latitude.

However, I find that I now need to restrict that set of airports by an addtional value in another column.

The formula I'm using is:

`=INDEX
    (
    A$1:A$7184,MATCH
        (
            MIN
                (
                IF
                    (

                        D1&","&E1<>D$1:D$7184&","&E$1:E$7184,
                        ABS(D1-D$1:D$7184)+ABS(E1-E$1:E$7184)
                    )
                ),
                IF
                    (
                        D1&","&E1<>D$1:D$7184&","&E$1:E$7184,
                        ABS(D1-D$1:D$7184)+ABS(E1-E$1:E$7184)
                    ),0
            )
    )`

The data set is comprised of around 7000 rows as per the below sample. I'm attempting to modify the above formula to find the next closest airport *which has a '1' in column f*. The next closest column contains the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `MINIFS` function :

```
=INDEX
    (A$1:A$7184,
    MATCH
        (
            MINIFS(SQRT(($D$1:$D$7184-D1)^2+($C$1:$C$7184-C1)^2),$E$1:$E$7184;"=1"),
            SQRT(($D$1:$D$7184-D1)^2+($C$1:$C$7184-C1)^2),
            0
        )
    )
```

Comment: I see that this is your answer from my other question. What's the purpose of the -E1 and -F1 values in the formula?

Comment: @TheMightyLlama : My bad, I updated my answer to fit your columns! ;)

Comment: the formula is evaluated with an error. I've uploaded the file if you want to give it a go... http://www.filedropper.com/workbook2

Comment: @TheMightyLlama : Which version of Excel do you have? I forgot to check but MINIFS is a 2016 function...

Comment: 15.23. Looks like 2016

Comment: @TheMightyLlama : Not sure... See : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MINIFS-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599 MINIFS function applies to: Excel 2016, Excel 2016 for Mac, ... IMPORTANT: This function is available if you are an Office 365 subscriber and have the latest version of Office installed.